# Migration from AIDL to Billing v4 shall i need the InAppBillingService(com.android.vending.billing)

Tags: android, billing, google-play-billing

While upgrading the billing library shall I need to remove the InAppBillingServices?

How can I test the app billing? Does the static test sku ids are enough to check the subscriptions in the v4 of billing library?

Comment: Did you read the [migration guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/migrate)?

Comment: Yes, I removed that vending. Stll I see the inappbillingservies

Comment: @ianhanniballake In the guide, it mentioned need to delete the permissions and IabHelper files. Shall i need to delete the .aidl file (InAppBillingService.aidl) file in the app?

Comment: I have used private IInAppBillingService mBillingService; used as mBillingService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service); How it will be changed.  onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) now it will be BillingResult.

Answer (score 0):

here is the tutorial for google play billing library v4.
https://medium.com/@alimehdipk/implementing-google-play-billing-library-v4-for-in-app-and-subscriptions-f4bc74c58ed0